# Defining an Exponential Object using almost an adjunction

Tags: category-theory

We know that exponential functor $(-)^X$ can be defined as right adjoint to the functor $ -\times X$.

Consider two $\frak{C}$-objects $X$ and $Y$ and a functor $F:\frak{C}\to \frak{C}$. Suppose $\frak{C}$$(Z \times X,Y) \cong \frak{C}$$(Z,F(Y))$ naturally in $Z$ (so *almost* an adjunction). Then I was wondering whether $F(Y)$ can be considered as the exponential object $Y^X$. I think the answer is yes and this is my attempt.

First take $Z=F(X)$. Let $ev: F(Y) \times X \to Y$ be the element in $\frak{C}$$(F(Y) \times X,Y)$ corresponding to the identity arrow $id_{F(Y)}:F(Y) \to F(Y)$ (my claim is that $ev$ is the evaluation arrow). Let $f:Z \times X \to Y$ be an arbitrary $\frak{C}$-arrow of this form. Let $\tilde{f}$ be the corresponding element in $\frak{C}$$(Z,F(Y))$. Consider the following naturality square:
[image]

Since the assignment $\tilde{(-)}$ is a bijection, it is easy to see $\tilde{f}$ is the only choice satisfying $f=ev(\tilde{f} \times id_X)$

Is my argument correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit ambiguous; have you fixed $X$? If I interpret your statement in the following way:

> Suppose $X\in\mathfrak{C}$ is given and $F^X:\mathfrak{C}\to\mathfrak{C}$ is a functor for which there are isomorphisms $\mathfrak{C}(X\times Z,Y)\cong\mathfrak{C}(Z,F^X(Y))$ which are natural in $Z$, for every $Y$ fixed. Is $F(Y)$ an exponential object $Y^X$, for every $Y$?

Well, yes. It is a well known principle that if you have a family of objects $A_Y:Y\in\mathfrak{C}$ for which isomorphisms $\lambda_{Y,Z}:\mathfrak{C}(L(Z),Y)\cong\mathfrak{C}(Z,A_Y)$ are given, naturally in $Z$ and for some functor $L$, then the object map $Y\mapsto A_Y$ *uniquely* inherits a functor structure such that $L\dashv A_\bullet$ under those isomorphisms $\lambda$. So you can *promote the weak adjunction to a full adjunction*. There is an extension of this to parametric adjunctions as well.

In your case, taking $A_Y:=F^X(Y)$ and $L:=X\times(-)$, you would just have to (**potentially**) change the functor $F^X$. It would still be true that each $A_Y:=F^X(Y)$ is an exponential object $Y^X$, but it would not necessarily be true that $F^X\cong(-)^X$ as functors; we may have to redefine $F^X$'s action on morphisms.

Let me slightly more formally state and prove my claim.

> Let $\mathfrak{C},\mathfrak{D}$ be locally small categories, $L:\mathfrak{C}\to\mathfrak{D}$ a functor and a class function $R:\mathsf{Ob}(\mathfrak{D})\to\mathsf{Ob}(\mathfrak{C})$ be given. Suppose there exists, for each $\partial\in\mathfrak{D}$, a natural isomorphism $\Delta^\partial:\mathfrak{D}(L(-),\partial)\cong\mathfrak{C}(-,R(\partial)):\mathfrak{C}^{\mathsf{op}}\to\mathsf{Set}$.
>
> Then $R$ lifts to a functor $R:\mathfrak{D}\to\mathfrak{C}$ which is right adjoint to $L$. This lifting is unique if we demand the adjunction isomorphism to be given by the $\Delta^\bullet$.
>
> Proof:
>
> Fix an arrow $f:\partial\to\partial'$ in $\mathfrak{D}$.
>
> $\omega_f:=\Delta^{\partial'}\mathfrak{D}(1,f)(\Delta^\partial)^{-1}$ defines a natural transformation $\mathfrak{C}(-,R(\partial))\to\mathfrak{C}(-,R(\partial'))$, which by one version of the Yoneda lemma must come from an arrow $R(\partial)\to R(\partial')$ which is uniquely specified; call this arrow $R(f)$. This puts a well-defined action of $R$ on morphisms.
>
> If $f=1$, the natural transformation in question is also the identity hence $R(1_\partial)=1_{R(\partial)}$.
>
> If we look at a composition $\partial\overset{f}{\to}\partial'\overset{g}{\to}\partial''$, observe $\omega_g\circ\omega_f=\omega_{g\circ f}$ since the middle terms $(\Delta^{\partial'})^{-1}\Delta^{\partial'}=1$ cancel and $\mathfrak{D}(1,-)$ is a functor. It follows from the *uniqueness* in Yoneda's lemma that $R(g)\circ R(f)=R(g\circ f)$. We see $R$ is now a functor.
>
> By construction, the isomorphisms $\Delta^\partial_\varsigma:\mathfrak{D}(L(\varsigma),\partial)\cong\mathfrak{C}(\varsigma,R(\partial))$ are natural in $\partial\in\mathfrak{D}$. By hypothesis, they were already natural in $\varsigma$. By an easy theorem, this implies they are jointly natural. Thus $L\dashv R$. Uniqueness is obvious.

If $R$ was the object function of some predefined functor,... *we would potentially have to alter the definition of $R$* to make it a right adjoint, say to some functor $R'$ where $R=R'$ *on objects* but not necessarily on morphisms.